# How to decipher matlab function syntax ambiguity

Tags: matlab

I cannot find this syntax anywhere

```
y = @(beta, x)x*beta;
```

where `x` is some vector or matrix lets say.  Is `@` used to reference another function so you can have more than one externally visiuble function in the same `.m` file?  Sorry I'm new to matlab but can't find this in the documentation

Comment: The function handle help page is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html). See in particular the exemple: 'sqr = @(x) x.^2;' Then 'a = sqr(5)' gives
a = 25.

Comment: see `doc function_handle`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html. You could have found this out by  `help @` and looking through the list of special characters for `@`

Comment: I don't understand why this question is voted negatively. `@ matlab` search in google gives nothing interesting, and typing `@` in the documentation leave the result page blank.

Comment: `help @` and `doc @` in Matlab itself both work fine and indicate that the "at" symbol is used for "function handle creation". Also `at matlab` in Google returns [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html) as the first hit (`@ matalab` is just poor Google skills unless you're looking for a Twitter handle).

Answer (score 4):

That is the way to define an anonymous function in Matlab. It is basically the same as

```
function result = y(beta, x)

result = x * beta;
```

but without needing an m-file or subfunction to define it. They can be constructed within other m-files or even within an expression. Typical use is as a throw-away function inside the call of some complex function that needs a function as one of its inputs, i.e.:

```
>> arrayfun(@(x) x^2, 1:10)

ans =

     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100
```

I personally use them a lot to refactor a list of repetitive statements

```
a = complex_expression(x, y, z, 1)
b = complex_expression(x, y, z, 3)
c = complex_expression(x, y, z, 8)
```

into

```
f = @(n) complex_expression(x, y, z, n)
a = f(1)
b = f(3)
c = f(8)
```

More [info](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) from the Mathworks. They are more or less the same as a lambda expression in Python.

Comment: is it ok for this to happen at the very beginning of a function where beta is not even define yet? can this be referenced later on

Comment: beta is one of the parameters of the anonymous function, exactly the same as when you would define it with `function result = y(beta, x)`, so beta gets replaced by whatever value you call the function with, so when you call `y(5, 10)`, beta will get the value 5 and the result will be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `@` as *anonymous* which means an unnamed function (technically, in MATLAB, you *must* give it a name since you cannot do e.g., `(@(x, y) x + y)(1, 2)`, that name is whatever variable you assign the anonymous function to).

The syntax `@(x, y) x + y` reads: create an anonymous `@` function with parameters `x` and `y` and return the result of the evaluation of the *expression* following the next closing parenthesis. In this case, that's the addition of `x` and `y`.

One thing that almost no one I know who uses MATLAB uses on a regular basis and instead uses `repmat` hell instead is `bsxfun` (it stands for binary singleton expansion).

With the expression `bsxfun(@plus, randn(1000, 20), randn(1000, 1))` you essentially `repmat` the right hand side 20 times to form a new matrix that you then pass to the `@plus` function handle. You can pass any function around this way. Take a look at `cellfun` and `arrayfun`. They are incredibly useful.